# Using the result of a function to filter the select inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I just cant wrap my head around this problem I've run into. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So basically I have a table of threads. These threads have a latitude and a longitude column.

I have a scalar-valued function my database that takes 2 sets of latlongs and determines the distance between the two.

What I want to do is create a stored procedure that selects threads with a "where" constraint uses the latlong in the selected threads and uses them in the function along with the supplied latlong from the stored procedure parameter (which is where the user is located), which should then return a result (in km), and then returns all threads that has a distance in km above the supplied minimum distance (another stored procedure parameter).

I tried to illustrate what I'm trying to do with an image, hopefully it doesn't cause even more confusion!

http://puu.sh/tT6Xm/75aa6817a1.png

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetThreadsInArea 
    @CountryCode nvarchar(10),
    @Latitude float,
    @Longtitude float
AS
    /* Use the result of this select in the function */
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Threads
    WHERE CountryCode = @CountryCode

    /* This is the function, but I just have no idea how to use it with the  select above */
    SELECT dbo.fnCalcDistanceKm(@lat1, @lat2, @lon1, @lon2)
    /* And now filter the first select from threads that has a distance below 10 km */
    WHERE Distance < 10
GO
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean cross apply?

Comment: search for "sql server cross apply" ....

Comment: Thanks for the hint Mitch. Though I have a little problem with what I just made with Cross Apply.

http://pastebin.com/9mNa55W7

I get the error:

Incorrect syntax near '10.0'.

Comment: Because you forgot the `END` (to close the `BEGIN`) before the `GO`